# ML-Kit for Android crash

Tags: android, api, kotlin, camera, google-mlkit

I am getting rare crashes while using ML-Kit Vision and I am not getting app level logs after crash. It is really difficult to know line of crash without getting app level logs. That is why I had to extract app level logs from OS logs (no filter in Android Studio) which was the reason for crash as I could guess. So it is not completely guaranteed that on your phone it will crash. Say, out of 10 I got 2-3 times it crashed on my device.

There's parent activity from which I am starting LivePreviewActivity and as soon as it starts I am initialising camera. It crashes at that time. It could also crash when leaving that activity when you click on back button on top left.

```
    --------- beginning of main
2021-01-12 22:28:30.286 706-706/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger expire 1 line
2021-01-12 22:28:30.287 706-706/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-01-12 22:28:31.280 992-1095/? I/ThermalEngine: Sensor:msm_therm:39000 mC
2021-01-12 22:28:31.284 706-706/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-01-12 22:28:31.579 15745-16030/? D/PowerManagerService: userActivityNoUpdateLocked: eventTime=114035435, event=2, flags=0x0, uid=1000
2021-01-12 22:28:31.580 15745-16030/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=114328435 (in 292990 ms)
2021-01-12 22:28:31.581 15745-16030/? D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x0, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, screenBrightnessOverride=-1, useAutoBrightness=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false, mIsVrModeEnabled= false, sQuiescent=false
2021-01-12 22:28:31.684 15745-16030/? D/PowerManagerService: userActivityNoUpdateLocked: eventTime=114035547, event=2, flags=0x0, uid=1000
```

[Complete crash logs here](https://pastebin.com/zU2sL7WK)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_live_preview)
    MainApp.getInstance().setupRetrofitWithCustomUrl()
    imgPreview = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview)
    txtProgress = findViewById(R.id.txtProgress)
    previewLayout = findViewById(R.id.previewLayout)
    txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult)

    txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult)
    txtEmpName = findViewById(R.id.txtEmpName)
    txtDate = findViewById(R.id.txtDate)
    txtTime = findViewById(R.id.txtTime)

    val toolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
      onBackPressed() // Implemented by activity
    }
//    imgPreview.visibility = View.GONE
//    txtProgress.visibility = View.GONE
    previewLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    txtResult.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    preview = findViewById(R.id.preview_view)
    if (preview == null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Preview is null")
    }

    graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay)
    if (graphicOverlay == null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "graphicOverlay is null")
    }

    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
    val options: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    options.add(OBJECT_DETECTION)
    options.add(OBJECT_DETECTION_CUSTOM)
    options.add(FACE_DETECTION)
    options.add(TEXT_RECOGNITION)
    options.add(BARCODE_SCANNING)
    options.add(IMAGE_LABELING)
    options.add(IMAGE_LABELING_CUSTOM)
    options.add(AUTOML_LABELING)
    options.add(POSE_DETECTION)

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    val dataAdapter =
      ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_style, options)

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.adapter = dataAdapter
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
    spinner.setSelection(2)

//    val facingSwitch = findViewById<ToggleButton>(R.id.facing_switch)
//    facingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)

    val settingsButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.settings_button)
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
      val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SettingsActivity::class.java)
      intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_LAUNCH_SOURCE, LaunchSource.LIVE_PREVIEW)
      startActivity(intent)
    }

    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
      createCameraSource(selectedModel)
    } else {
      runtimePermissions
    }
  }
```

[Complete code here](https://pastebin.com/CQc2xRSs)

[Original file here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/LivePreviewActivity.kt)

Comment: In general, the crash may happen when the image data was released before it is completely processed by native.

Comment: @Shiyu thanks for reply. How do I solve this? The original Camera API is used in this. Should I try CameraX API

Comment: You could definitely try CameraX APIs, since they handle more edge cases. Did you see the crash with original ML Kit sample app?

Comment: @bhusan2k Friendly ping, thanks!